# How to get RTC work item attribute data using java API?

Tags: java, api, rtc

I am using below code and it returns some information about "Filed Against"
attribute. But there I am not able to find attribute data. Please help

```
IAttribute someAttribute= workItemClient.findAttribute(projectAreaHandle, workItem.CATEGORY_PROPERTY, monitor);
```

Using below code to find out the work item by Id :

```
workItemClient = (IWorkItemClient) repo.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
                int id = new Integer("339406").intValue();  
                IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, monitor);
```

using this work item I want to fetch parent and children like Epic and story work items related to the work item. And then there attributes like story status, story planned for etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/206015/how-to-get-the-workitems-based-on-filed-against-value):

> You can't just put a string in there, I think.
>   You have to find the category object from the string and then put in the `ICategory` object.

That means:

```
private static String CATEGORY_NAME = "UI1"; 
List<ICategory> findCategories = workItemCommon.findCategories(projectArea, ICategory.FULL_PROFILE, monitor); 
    for(ICategory category : findCategories) { 
          if(category.getName().contains(CATEGORY_NAME)){ 
              filedAgainstAttribute = QueryableAttributes.getFactory(IWorkItem.ITEM_TYPE).findAttribute(projectArea, IWorkItem.CATEGORY_PROPERTY, auditableClient, monitor); 
                    filedAgainstExpression = new AttributeExpression(filedAgainstAttribute, AttributeOperation.EQUALS, category);
       } 
  }
```

Comment: I spent a few very painful hours myself to do something useful with the RTC APIs. From that point of view, I wish I could upvote this multiple times. Just to make up for the energy that it probably cost you at some point to acquire the knowledge ...

Comment: @GhostCat Can you please share the code snippet, I am trying to find out the attributes data and I only have feature id, using that i have work item but further I have no idea how to fetch parent and children of the work item and then their attributes

Comment: @VonC, Thanks for the response, actually I have feature Id and need to create one report which contains all parent and child work items in that and all their attributes. Any help would really be appreciated. I am struggling with the RTC APIs from last one week but didn't get any luck. Please help

Comment: @RinkalGarg Your question did not mention anything about and child work items: can you edit your question to show a bit more of the code you have and of what is missing?

Comment: @RinkalGarg I didn't work this specific thing. It was more of a generic rant about how painful working it is to work with RTC APIs. Sorry pal, no specific code that I could pass along here. If I had that, I would have written an answer already ;-)

Comment: @RinkalGarg Apparently, findLinksBySource is key (as in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/70215/fetching-parent-workitem-using-plain-java-api?redirect=%2Fforum%2Fquestions%2F70215%2Ffetching-parent-workitem-using-plain-java-api). Regarding attributes: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/84545/how-to-get-work-item-found-in-attribute-value

Comment: @VonC Thanks for you help, Now I have parent and child links with me. Is there any way to find out work item using that link or if we can cast that link into IWorkItem. Please respond.